# What is the proper way to access properties in a URL in isolated Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have been looking all over to see if there is a different way to access parameters being passed in an Isolated Azure Function (.NET 5)

**Here is my route:** Route = "v1/session/find/{ipAddress}/{sessionId}"

**More info full method signature:**
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,"get", Route = "v1/session/find/{ipAddress}/{sessionId}")] HttpRequestData req,
FunctionContext executionContext)

**Here is how I access those parameters and clean them up:**

```
        var ipAddress = req.Url.Segments[5];
        ipAddress = ipAddress.TrimEnd(new[] { '/' });
        ipAddress = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ipAddress).Trim();
        var sessionId = req.Url.Segments[6];
        sessionId = sessionId.TrimEnd(new[] {'/'});
        sessionId = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(sessionId).Trim();
```

I am missing something or is this the only way to get those route parameters for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.Net 5**

@fgalarraga88, you're right.  I failed to see that you specifically stated .Net 5.  Here is the code that should work for .Net 5 Isolated.  I tested this locally in VS 2019 16.10 and it worked.

Simply set the Route using the attribute (providing your pattern with the params in curly braces) and then add the expected route parameters as parameters to the method.  It's that simple.

```
public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/session/find/{ipAddress}/{sessionId}")] 
   HttpRequestData req, 
   string ipAddress, 
   string sessionId,
   FunctionContext executionContext)
   {
      var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

      response.WriteString($"IP Addresss: {ipAddress} and Session Id: {sessionId}");

      return response;
   }
```

Leaving my original answer for reference should it prove useful to others.

**.Net Core 3.1**

Review the docs for HttpTrigger (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#customize-the-http-endpoint) and it outlines how to deal with route variables.

Per those docs, customize the route property:

```
{
    "bindings": [
    {
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "name": "req",
        "direction": "in",
        "methods": [ "get" ],
        "route": "products/{category:alpha}/{id:int?}"
    },
    {
        "type": "http",
        "name": "res",
        "direction": "out"
    }
    ]
}
```

Would result in the following method signature for your C# function:

```
public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, string category, int? id, ILogger log)
{
    var message = String.Format($"Category: {category}, ID: {id}");
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(message);
}
```

And you have access to "category" and "id" without any custom segment parsing.  Just use this example with your route and substitute in the ipAddress and sessionId vars.

Comment: This is for .NET Core 3.1 Functions.  I am working with .NET 5 Functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-developer-howtos?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs) Which seem to work completely different.

Comment: That is a winner.  Thank you for the insight, worked like a charm.  Wish I could up vote it but need more post to do so.

Comment: @fgalarraga88, you may not be able to up vote the answer, but you should be able to mark it as the Accepted Answer regardless of your rep.  There should be a Checkmark icon that will turn green when you accept it.